Domain $C^{2+\alpha}$ proprieties
Let $0<\alpha<1$.
Hi! I am reading the paper: How to appoximate the heat equation with Neumann Boundary Condition by nonLocal Diffusion Problem (https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00205-007-0062-8.pdf [page 9 of pdf])
and I am a quite a bit longer in this statement and I really don’t know why this is happen.

Why the sets above is in $\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega$ and $\Omega$, respectively? I didn’t understand by the definition of $C^{2+\alpha}$! I saw this happen in a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I can’t generalize. Can someone explain or give me a type?
